# ¿Como puedo filtrar en un array todos los objetos que tengan ese valor en angular?

Tags: array, angular, ionic, objeto, filtro

Este es mi .ts en el cual mando a llamar una función getArchivo() de mi service y en el cual le asigno todos los datos al this.archivos

El problema viene que al filtrar con un valor ('Gestion') que sea igual al campo de mi colección razón_archivado array no no funciona me muestra el array vacío, intente con filter y foreach ademas de ng-repeat en el html con filter pero tampoco

```
export class ArchivoPage implements OnInit {
  archivo: any;
  items: any;
  array: any;
  busqueda;
  nuevoArray: any;
  constructor(public hzoService: HallazgoService) {
    this.archivo =[];
    this.items = [];
    this.array = [];
    this.nuevoArray=[];
   }

 getArchivo(){
    this.hzoService.getArchivo().then((res) =>{
      this.archivo = this.hzoService.archivo.hallazgos;
   const filter = this.archivo.filter((item) => item.razon_archivado == 'Gestion');
console.log(filter);
 
   }, (err) =>{

    });
  }
```

Esta es mi pagina html y funciona bien sin usar el filtrado

```
<ion-row class="this" *ngFor="let hallazgo of archivo | filter:busqueda">
                            <ion-col class="contenido movil">
                                <ion-button (click)='generatePDF(hallazgo)' color="danger">PDF</ion-button>
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col class="contenido">
                                {{hallazgo.folio}}
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col class="contenido">
                                {{hallazgo.central.name}}
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col class="contenido">
                                {{hallazgo.area}}
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col class="contenido">
                                {{hallazgo.activity}}
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col class="contenido">
                                {{hallazgo.task}}
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col class="contenido" [ngClass]="{ rojo: hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'eliminado', naranja: hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'descartado', verde: hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'concluido', azulA: hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'Hallazgo', azulB: hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'OTs', azulC: hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'Revisión', gest: hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'Gestión'}">
                                {{hallazgo.razon_archivado}}
                            </ion-col>
```

Esta es mi función del back que mando a llamar

```
const ArchiveroCtrl = {};

ArchiveroCtrl.getArchivero = async(req, res) => {
    await Hallazgos.find({ centroManto: req.user.cm[0] })
        .populate('central', 'name')
        .sort({ razon_archivado: 1, fecha_archivado: -1 })
        .exec((err, hallazgos) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err
                });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({
                ok: true,
                count: hallazgos.length,
                hallazgos
            })
        });
}

router.get('/archivero', ArchiveroCtrl.getArchivero);
```

Comment: No debería ser: `this.archivo = res;`?

Comment: No comprendo muy bien como aplicar lo que me acabas de decir, si me puedes explicar mejor te lo agradecería

Comment: Tienes la línea: `this.archivo = this.hzoService.archivo.hallazgos;` los datos no deberían estar en la variable `res`?

Comment: Al cambiarlo como me aconsejas no muestra los datos y al usar hallazgos si muestra los datos

Comment: Ok, solo era una curiosidad. Y el valor de `razon_archivado` es `Gestion` o `Gestión`? Porque veo que en la vista usas la condición `gest: hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'Gestión'` Y en el filtro es `item.razon_archivado == 'Gestion'` Y ese acento hace la diferencia.

Comment: Buena observación y te agradezco mucho, ya me mostró en la consola el array con los datos ahora solo me falta mostrarlos en la tabla con un ion select tu que me recomiendas hacer?

Comment: Ahí si no sé xD. Solo tengo experiencia con Angular no con Ionic.

Comment: No te preocupes xD solo una duda mas, ya mande a llamar para que solo mostrara esos datos en el array aquí pero sigue mostrando todos sabes a que se debe?

Comment: doRefresh(event){
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    this.filter;
    this.getArchivo();

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      //this.editarHallazgos();
  
      event.target.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getArchivo();
  }

Comment: Si no has modificado el código entonces los datos filtrados están en la variable `filter` la cual debe asignarse  `this.archivo = filter;`

Comment: Exacto justo hice eso y apenas te ibas decir que funciono y ya me habías dado la respuesta, de verdad muchas gracias

Comment: ¿como te puntúo o como te doy gratificación aquí?, la verdad soy nuevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**

El error está en la condición del filtro `item.razon_archivado == 'Gestion'`. En la vista está la condición `hallazgo.razon_archivado == 'Gestión'`. El acento hace que ambas cadenas sean diferentes.

**2**

Para que los datos filtrados se actualicen en la vista deben asignarse a la variable `archivo`:

```
const filter = this.archivo.filter((item) => item.razon_archivado == 'Gestión');
this.archivo = filter;
```